# Strange boot up screen 2019 MacBook Pro

Tags: mac, startup

When restart or boot up my 2019 MacBook Pro, immediately after I enter my password at the login screen, a black screen appears with white words. The words are scrolling and they appear to be some sort of console output. Does anyone know what this is and if it’s indicative of a problem? This occurs every time the machine is restarted unless I boot into safe mode.

Comment: Is this *after* you [log in to macOS](http://cdn.osxdaily.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/howto-take-screenshots-of-login-screen-mac-os-x-610x359.jpg) or after you enter your [firmware password](https://www.imore.com/sites/imore.com/files/styles/large/public/field/image/2014/04/firmware_password_mac_hero.jpg?itok=xCwbBdbQ)

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like your Mac is starting up in '[Verbose Mode](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201573)'.

This shouldn't normally happen, unless you hold down the required key combination, or unless your Mac's NVRAM has been set to always start verbose.

Try [resetting the PRAM](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204063) to clear the boot arguments.

If that doesn't work, try the following Terminal command:

```
sudo nvram boot-args=""
```

(Assuming you don't have a need for any other custom nvram parameters.)